# I meet an ImportError when I read a .pkl file

Tags: python

I cloned some code from github,when I want to run it,it errors

```
File "D:/Project/Pycharm/SeqGAN/sequence_gan.py", line 186, in <module>
main()
File "D:/Project/Pycharm/SeqGAN/sequence_gan.py", line 93, in main
target_params = pickle.load(f)
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.core.multiarray\r'
```

it seems that the pkl file dumps in a mac or linux and when i can't read it on windows, but i don't konw how to solve it

update:I have already installed numpy before and it has the function.I think it not cause by numpy.May be it cause by "\r".I have tried to add "encoding='utf-8'" in pickle.load(), it's useless.

Comment: Do you have numpy module installed in your system ? A little googling would have solved your problem.

Comment: I have already installed numpy before and it has the function.May be it's "\r" cause the problem, i think.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you don't have `numpy` installed on your machine. Unpickling will work if you have that [installed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html).

Comment: No, I have already installed numpy before and it has the function.May be it's "\r" cause the problem.